Total variation distance discrete law empirical process
Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be iid random variables with law $P$, a discrete law.
We denote $P_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \delta_{X_i}$ the empirical process. I would like to show that :
$d_{TV}(P_n,P)$ converges to $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity almost surely.
I try to take use the following result :
for any measurable function $f$ from $[-1,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, one has :
$d_{TV}(P_n,P) \leq \frac{1}{2} sup |P_n(f) - P(f)|$
and to write $P$ as a sum of Diracs, $P = \sum_k a_k \delta_k$ with $a_k$ the support of $P$ but I fail to go further.
Any help ? Please. Thanks in advance.
